# VBA - Delete all rows after last row in copied data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to figure out the code to delete all the rows after the last row of my copied data

I am copying data from worksheet A to worksheet B. Worksheet B already has data in it. if the number of rows in worksheet A is less than worksheet B, I want to delete all the rows that were not copied into worksheet B from worksheet A.

EG: Worksheet A = 50 Rows
Worksheet B = 60 Rows.
I copy Worksheet A to worksheet B, I want to delete the 10 Rows that were not part of Worksheet A.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet
Dim shPriorWeek As Worksheet
Dim lr3 As Long

Set shCurrentWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
Set shPriorWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Week")
lr3 = shPriorWeek.Range(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Copies necessary rows in CurrentWeek tab to PriorWeek tab
shCurrentWeek.Range("A4:X" & lr).Copy shPriorWeek.Range("A2")
shPriorWeek.Range("A4:X" & lr3 + 1 & ":A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
```

I am relatively sure my lr3 is set wrong... not sure how to fix.

thanks!

Comment: why don't you just clear the contents before you paste your new data?

Comment: it affects formulas in Worksheet A that are based off data in worksheet B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code says that `shCurrentWeek.Range("A4:X" & lr).Copy shPriorWeek.Range("A2")` (In other words, you're copying from [starting row 4] to [starting row 2]) you could just forget about `lr3` and do the following (I believe):

```
shCurrentWeek.Range("A4:X" & lr).Copy shPriorWeek.Range("A2")
shPriorWeek.Range("A" & lr-2 & ":A10000").EntireRow.Delete
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have previously defined lr pertaining to a different sheet.

Comment: ... I don't understand what that has to do with anything - You copy from `"A4"` to `"X" & lr` and paste srarting at `"A2"`, so you need to delete from `lr-2` onwards, no???

Comment: I suppose that makes sense... but I tried to do the code and I came up with an error: `Method 'range' of object'_Worksheet' failed`. Just for reference: `lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: ... If you're in Excel versions previous to 2007, you need to set the range to less than 65000 rows - That's my guess as to what's going on... `shPriorWeek.Range("A" & lr-2 & "A65000").EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: I am using excel 2007 and the original code was only 10000 so I do not believe this is the problem. I am still convinced the problem lies within `lr`. But I'm not sure of course.

Comment: Sorry - I just saw, I missed the `":"` - Change that line to `shPriorWeek.Range("A" & lr-2 & ":A10000").EntireRow.Delete` - That will do it!

Comment: EXCELLENT. Thank you haha. Love these silly "little" mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

you want `lr3` to be the row number of the last row (not the offset compared to your pasted data:

```
lr3 = shPriorWeek.Rows.Count
```

Then the delete statement should read:

```
shPriorWeek.Range("A4:A" & lr3).EntireRow.Delete
```

Alternatively first clearing THEN pasting (as suggested in the comments) is a good way as well, and very clean.

Comment: My original code was clearing contents, but formulas become affected and the data becomes wrong. Unfortunately, your code above does not work for me as it is deleting all the rows.